# Pull a Dictionary Entry using Date only

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary of type `Dictionary<DateTime, Cars>`

In the sample dictionary below, is it possible to pick out the value for june 2nd using the date only as the Key?

```
 [0]: {[{31-May-2022 6:12:30 AM}, {Cars}]}
 [1]: {[{01-Jun-2022 8:52:10 AM}, {Cars}]}
 [2]: {[{02-Jun-2022 6:19:17 AM}, {Cars}]}
 [3]: {[{03-Jun-2022 6:27:39 AM}, {Cars}]}
 [4]: {[{04-Jun-2022 6:47:00 AM}, {Cars}]}
```

thanks!

Comment: are the DateTime objects as the key?

Comment: yes the datetime is the key unfortunately.. I only have the dates.. was wondering if its possible to match the date only so i can pickout the object Cars for that day

Comment: @ARC yes correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a custom `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` implementation if passed to your dictionary on creation.

```
public class DictionaryDateTimeComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateTime>
{
    public bool Equals(DateTime x, DateTime y)
    {
        return x.Date == y.Date;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DateTime obj)
    {
        return obj.Date.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This allows you to use it like so:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime, Cars>(new DictionaryDateTimeComparer())
    {
        { DateTime.Parse("2022-05-31 6:12:30 AM"), new Cars { Id = 1 } },
        { DateTime.Parse("2022-06-01 8:53:10 AM"), new Cars { Id = 2 } }
    };
    
var car = dictionary[DateTime.Parse("2022-05-31")];
```

which returns the first entry.

---

If this is not a dictionary that you control, you can either project it to a new dictionary with:

```
var copiedDictionary = 
    new Dictionary<DateTime, Cars>(dictionary, new DictionaryDateTimeComparer());
```

or you can iterate over it which will certainly have worse performance and may not be feasible performance-wise, depending on the number of entries:

```
var car = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Date == DateTime.Parse("2022-05-31")).Value;
```

Comment: yeah unfortunately, the dictionary is not something I have control of.  The dictionary however should not contain no more than 10 entries. I guess iteration over it would work.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a Dictionary that was created without that definition of "equality", then the best you can do is iterate through the keys.

You could alternatively create the dictionary with a `IEqualityComparer<DateTime>` class that defines "equality" as looking at the date only:

```
class DateEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateTime>
{
    public bool Equals(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
    {
        if(d1.Date == d2.Date)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DateTime d)
    {
        return d.Date.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Note that:

- This class would need to be used to *create* the dictionary; it could not be used after the fact
- It would prevent the dictionary from having multiple `DateTime` key values with the same date; Adding a key with the same date but a different time would create a collision

Comment: may i ask what is the purpose of the GetHashCode() ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-6.0

Comment: It is used to organize keys in a hash-based collection (like `Dictionary`). It is a first check to see if two objects _might_ be equal

Comment: Two "equal" objects _must_ generate the same hash code, but two objects with the same hash code may do not have to be equal