# how to compare the entered contents of a variable in the cache memory in .Net Framework 4.8 C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, helper

**Hi**

I need help from I have to class, this class get price of gold using API NBP.

```
 const string uriBase = "http://api.nbp.pl/api/cenyzlota/";
  
    public double get_price(DateTime date)
    {
        // wpisanie daty w formacie YYYY-MM-DD z console.ReadLine()
        
        string baseDate = @"^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$";
        Console.WriteLine("Podaj datę w formacie YYYY-MM-DD:");
        string dateStr = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Regex.IsMatch(dateStr, baseDate))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data poprawna");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data niepoprawna");
        }
                    
        // wysłanie zapytania do API po odpowiedź
        string uriQuery = uriBase + dateStr;

        // zwracanie ceny złota z podanego z konsoli dnia
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uriQuery);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync().Result;
        string json = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        string[] jsonSplit = json.Split(new string[] { "cena" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string[] jsonSplit2 = jsonSplit[1].Split(new string[] { "data" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        //usunięcie nawiasów i znaków specjalnych z ceny złota
        string jsonSplit3 = jsonSplit2[0].Replace(":", "");
        string jsonSplit4 = jsonSplit3.Replace("\"", "");
        string jsonSplit5 = jsonSplit4.Replace(" ", "");
        string jsonSplit6 = jsonSplit5.Replace(",", "");
        string jsonSplit7 = jsonSplit6.Replace("}", "");
        string jsonSplit8 = jsonSplit7.Replace("]", "");
        string jsonSplit9 = jsonSplit8.Replace("[", "");


        // podanie ceny złota z podanego dnia po usunięci z niej znaków specjalnych
        string price = jsonSplit9;
        Console.WriteLine("Cena złota z dnia " + dateStr + " wynosi: " + price + " zł");

        Console.WriteLine("Zostnie zapisane do pliku");
        Console.ReadLine();

        //zapisanie wyniku do pliku w nowej linii
        string path = @"C:\Users\tmysz\Desktop\json.txt";

        File.AppendAllText(path, dateStr + " " + price + Environment.NewLine);


        //sprawdzenie czy plik istnieje
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Plik istnieje");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Plik nie istnieje");
        }

        //sprawdzenie czy wpis w pliku jest pusty
        if (File.ReadAllText(path) == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Plik jest pusty");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Plik nie jest pusty");
        }



        return 0;
    }
```

and I have a other class "Proxy", class Proxy  is an implementation of the helper design pattern. Proxy send to API question of date, and if you send this same date secound time, Proxy don't send question to API. I implemented it like this:

```
 internal class GoldServiceProxy : GoldService
{

  
    private readonly GoldService goldService;
    private readonly Dictionary<DateTime, double> cache = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();

    public GoldServiceProxy(GoldService goldService)
    {
        this.goldService = goldService;
    }

    public double get_price(DateTime date)
    {
        if (cache.ContainsKey(date))
        {
            return cache[date];
        }
        else
        {
            double price = goldService.get_price(date);
            cache.Add(date, price);
            return price;
        }
    }
     

}
```

using

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                GoldServiceProxy goldServiceProxy = new GoldServiceProxy(new GoldService());
                var price = goldServiceProxy.get_price(DateTime.Now);
                Console.WriteLine(price);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("Data nie została zanleziona");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Wciśnij dowolny klawisz aby zakończyć");
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
```

And Proxy don't work, enyone whot to help me?
I think there is a bug in this code

```
 public double get_price(DateTime date)
    {
        if (cache.ContainsKey(date))
        {
            return cache[date];
        }
        else
        {
            double price = goldService.get_price(date);
            cache.Add(date, price);
            return price;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you add the same date with different times in the dictionary **cache** when you're using `DateTime`, that why the Proxy keep send question to API even in even if you writing this date again.

this how it looks like:

```
 [0]: {[{2022-11-07 6:12:30 AM}, {258.25}]}
 [1]: {[{2022-11-07 6:20:10 AM}, {258.25}]}
 [2]: {[{2022-11-07 6:52:17 AM}, {258.25}]}
```

check this solution :[Pull a Dictionary Entry using Date only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73228025/pull-a-dictionary-entry-using-date-only)
and you must declared **cache** as static

Comment: can you help me  write this code?

Comment: i have the same issue "cannot convert form `string` to `System.Date.Time`